# How to set unique id value for kendo ui grid?

Tags: kendo-ui

I am very new to Kendo UI. I am using grid control.

I have issue in selecting or changing background color of a particular row. Can anyone help me how can I do this?

My code goes something like this

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<EmpModel>()                        
     .Name("tgrid")                        
     .Columns(columns =>
           {
             columns.Bound(x => x.EmpId).Width(100).Title("Emp Id");
             columns.Bound(x => x.EmpNameName).Width(100).Title("Emp Name");
             columns.Bound(x => x.Comments).Width(100).Title("Comments”);
           })
```

In ViewData["EmpId"] I have EmpId stored.
ViewData["EmpId"] = 110023

When the above grid is populated I want to highlight or select or expand the row has EmpId 110023.

What is the best way to do?

Thanks in advance
Param

Thanks in advance
Param

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear, please clarify. Basically the uid field of your model contains the unique identifier which is added to each TR automatically by the Grid. If you want to style the columns based on the data check [this](http://www.kendoui.com/code-library/mvc/grid/submit-form-containing-grid-along-with-other-input-elements.aspx) code library.